# how to check the following in matlab?

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

I have a problem with writing a simple code. 
I am trying to check if my matrix is [a 0 0 ;0 a 0;0 0 a,b 0 0;0 b 0;0 0 b] (it's like stacking two different identity matrices).

How can I do this in matlab?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are `a` and `b`?

Comment: oh they are just random numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always use the Matlab Eye function to create a stacked identity matrix and check the equivalency. The ; creates a new row so your effectively vertically concatenating the two identity matrices.

```
stackedE = [eye(3);eye(3)];
testMat = [1,0,0;0,1,0;0,0,1;1,0,0;0,1,0;0,0,1];
testMat == stackedE
```

If you wish to check for A and B you can multiply the identity matrices by these constants:

```
A = 2;
B = 3;
stackedE = [eye(3)*A;eye(3)*B];
testMat = [A,0,0;0,A,0;0,0,A;B,0,0;0,B,0;0,0,B];
testMat == stackedE
```